# JavaScript prompt redirect after user clicks OK

Tags: javascript

I was wondering how I might redirect to a page after a user enter information into a prompt and clicks OK, something like this:

```
var Input = prompt("Message:");
if (//Button clicked, and Input not empty\\) {
    //Sanitize input
    //Redirect to https://www.MyWeb.com/?Message=INPUT
}
```

Lots of people ask about things like `alert()` and `confirm()`, but I haven't found anything to do with `prompt()`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to redirect to another webpage?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/503093/how-to-redirect-to-another-webpage)

Comment: I know how to redirect, I just need to know how I would do this with both a `prompt()` and logic, most people do this with an `alert()`

Comment: Just like you did. The script stops and only continues once you entered something in the message box.

Answer (score 1):

This page will help you.

https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_prompt.asp

```
var Input = prompt("Message:");

if(Input.trim() != "" && Input == "your key")
{
    location.href = "/togo";
}
else
{
    alert("Fail!");
}
```

Is that what I understand?

good luck!

Answer (score 0):

You can try like this

```
    var txt;
    if (confirm("Press a button!") == true) {
        txt = "You pressed OK!";
    } else {
        txt = "You pressed Cancel!";
    }
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = txt;
```

With prompt:

```
   var msg = prompt("Custom Header:");
    if (msg.length > 0) { 
        console.log('Message Added ')
    } else {
        console.log('Its empty')
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try like this .use with [`trim()`](https://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=4&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwi6leKYnrPWAhUUR48KHQqtDHIQFgg1MAM&url=https%3A%2F%2Fdeveloper.mozilla.org%2Fen%2Fdocs%2FWeb%2FJavaScript%2FReference%2FGlobal_Objects%2FString%2Ftrim&usg=AFQjCNHplwP8uGVxgtKYMhsiv7EE8F9cMw) it  remove the unwanted space from the string

```js
var str = prompt("Message:");
if(str == null){
  console.log('pressed cancel')
}
else if (str.trim()) { //validate is not empty with empty space also
  console.log('valid')
  //window.location.href = "url"
} else {
  console.log('empty')
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I thought up the following code:

```
var Text = prompt ( "Message" );
if (Text != "" && Text != null) {
    Text = Text.trim (  );
    location.href = "https://www." + Text + ".com/"
} else {
    document.write ( "Error!" );
}
```

It checks if the user either:

1. Clicked cancel
2. Clicked OK, but input nothing

The `location.href` and `document.write` were only for bug testing.